# Print command response into .csv table

Tags: python, excel, file, command, output

I don't have much programming skills, but I need to send a output of a command into .csv table. I managed to create this, but it prints only 1st line of the table instead whole table, and I don't know how to procceed futher with turning it into csv.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date 
import sys
import os
import time

today1 = date.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
strTime = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
  
command = 'My command here'
cmd = session.command()
response = cmd.execute(command)
element_group = response.get_output()

table = element_group.groups()[0]

for cell in table[0]:
    print(cell.labels()[0] + ' , ' + '\t', end='')
print('\n')
for cell in table[5]:
    print(cell.value() + ' , ', end='')
print('\n')
```

I have tried script in description. I was expecting to print whole table and turning it into .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Here is the script I wanted.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
from datetime import date 
import sys
import os
import time

today1 = date.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
strTime = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')

command = 'My command here'
cmd = session.command()
response = cmd.execute(command)
element_group = response.get_output()
table = element_group.groups()[0]

header = [cell.labels()[0] for cell in table[0]]
rows = [[cell.value() for cell in row] for row in table]

directory = 'location'
filename = directory + 'filename' + today1 + '.csv'
with open(filename, mode='w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).